# Stripe SCA migration, how do I get the PaymentIntent 'client_secret'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm in the process to migrate my stripe integration to the new SCA european regulation. I'm using Stripe Billing with the stripe gem (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby), Rails 5.2 (ruby 2.6.4). I also have turbolinks 'on'.

I'm struggling with the 3D secure authentication, the Stripe.js script should handle this smoothly, but I can't manage to feed the variable that I need in order to do it.

The documentation says that the Billing engine creates a PaymentIntent, so I don't have to create it my self. With this object must come a client_cecret, that I have to pass to the view. I will do this with the gon gem(https://github.com/gazay/gon). To get this secret, I have to 'expand' the subscription object with the 'latest_invoice.payment_intent', according to Stripe docs, and then pass the 'latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret' to a variable, that later, the javascript will use to handle the payment or the 2FA with 3D secure via '.handleCardPayment'.

This is my registration_controller.rb's create_subscription action (I use devise):

```rb
def create_subscription
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:stripe_api_key]

    plan_id = params[:plan_id]
    plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    customer = if @user.stripe_id?
                 Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_id)
               else
                 Stripe::Customer.create(email: @user.email, source: token)
               end
    subscription = customer.subscriptions.create(
      items: [
        {
          plan: plan_id
        }

      ],
      expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
    )
    gon.intent = subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent


    options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id,
      stripe_subscription_id: subscription.id,
      subscribed: true,
      plan: plan_id
    }

    options.merge!(
      card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
      card_type: params[:user][:card_type]
    ) if params[:user][:card_last4]

    @user.update(options)

    flash[:success] = "¡Se ha creado la suscripción correctamente!"
  end
```

Then here is my subscriptions.js script:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  const publishableKey = document.querySelector("meta[name='stripe-key']").content;
  const stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);

  const elements = stripe.elements({
    locale: 'es'
  });

  const style = {
    base: {
      color: "#32325d",
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: "16px",
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",

      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#CFD7DF"
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#E25950"
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  const card = elements.create('card', { style });

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.

  card.mount('#card-element');



  card.addEventListener('change', ({ error }) => {

    const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (error) {
      displayError.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
  const form = document.getElementById('new_user');

  form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(card);

    if (error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
    const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      // handle the payment (pass, pyment error or 2FA)
      const clientSecret = gon.intent.client_secret;

      const { paymentIntent, error } =
        await stripe.handleCardPayment(
          clientSecret, card, {
          save_payment_method: true,
          setup_future_usage: 'off_session'
          }
        );
      if (error) {
        const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = error.message;
      } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      // stripeTokenHandler(token);
        const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
          // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          const form = document.getElementById('new_user');
          const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
          form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

          ["type", "last4", "exp_month", "exp_year"].forEach(function (field) {
            addCardField(form, token, field);
          });

          // Submit the form
          form.submit();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function addCardField(form, token, field) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', "user[card_" + field + "]");
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.card[field]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  }
});
```

With this configuration, when I try to get the 3D secure's modal with a stripe testing card number, I get an error:

> subscriptions.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read > property 'client_secret' of undefined at HTMLFormElement. (subscriptions.js:61)

I've tryed to pass the variable in Stripe Doc's way (data-secret in the button tag) but I get the same error (or similar).

Seem's clear that the variable is not there, but, **how could I pass it right? What am I missing?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Deikka, There are several possibilities that might result in this error. 1. Gon is not properly setup. can you try to `console.log(gon)` or set a break point on your chrome dev tool to make sure the Gon is setup correct with the variable? 
2. You are creating subscriptions with a trial period, in this case, `latest_invoice.payment_intent` will be `null` since there will be no immediate payment needed to be done, but there will be `pending_setup_intent` available 
Could you confirm which case it is for your case?

Comment: Hi @wsw, yes, It seems that Gon is not getting the subscription value... :( But it's weird, i'm using gon in other controlles and seems to work fine... I don't know... Thansk anyway, I'l try another options.